# CuPy error: failed to open nvrtc-builtins64_101.dll

Tags: cupy

I'm using CUDA Toolkit 10.1, my PATH is set correctly.

I am compiling:

```
import cupy
x = cupy.array([1., 2., 3.])
y = cupy.arange(10)
```

This gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\cupy\cuda\compiler.py", line 625, in compile
    nvrtc.compileProgram(self.ptr, options)
  File "cupy_backends\cuda\libs\nvrtc.pyx", line 133, in cupy_backends.cuda.libs.nvrtc.compileProgram
  File "cupy_backends\cuda\libs\nvrtc.pyx", line 145, in cupy_backends.cuda.libs.nvrtc.compileProgram
  File "cupy_backends\cuda\libs\nvrtc.pyx", line 64, in cupy_backends.cuda.libs.nvrtc.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.libs.nvrtc.NVRTCError: NVRTC_ERROR unknown (7)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Dropbox\Emil\Binance\a.py", line 4, in <module>
    y = cupy.arange(10)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\cupy\_creation\ranges.py", line 57, in arange
    _arange_ufunc(typ(start), typ(step), ret, dtype=dtype)
  File "cupy\_core\_kernel.pyx", line 1185, in cupy._core._kernel.ufunc.__call__
  File "cupy\_core\_kernel.pyx", line 1212, in cupy._core._kernel.ufunc._get_ufunc_kernel
  File "cupy\_core\_kernel.pyx", line 952, in cupy._core._kernel._get_ufunc_kernel
  File "cupy\_core\_kernel.pyx", line 62, in cupy._core._kernel._get_simple_elementwise_kernel
  File "cupy\_core\core.pyx", line 2030, in cupy._core.core.compile_with_cache
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\cupy\cuda\compiler.py", line 434, in compile_with_cache
    return _compile_with_cache_cuda(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\cupy\cuda\compiler.py", line 476, in _compile_with_cache_cuda
    base = _preprocess('', options, arch, backend)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\cupy\cuda\compiler.py", line 375, in _preprocess
    result, _ = prog.compile(options)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\cupy\cuda\compiler.py", line 637, in compile
    raise CompileException(log, self.src, self.name, options,
cupy.cuda.compiler.CompileException: nvrtc: error: failed to open nvrtc-builtins64_101.dll.
  Make sure that nvrtc-builtins64_101.dll is installed correctly.
```

I checked, the required DLL is in the \bin folder. What could be wrong here?

Show-config data is below

```
OS                           : Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
Python Version               : 3.9.1
CuPy Version                 : 9.3.0
CuPy Platform                : NVIDIA CUDA
NumPy Version                : 1.19.5
SciPy Version                : 1.6.2
Cython Build Version         : 0.29.24
Cython Runtime Version       : None
CUDA Root                    : C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1
nvcc PATH                    : C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin\nvcc.EXE
CUDA Build Version           : 10010
CUDA Driver Version          : 11040
CUDA Runtime Version         : 10010
cuBLAS Version               : (available)
cuFFT Version                : 10010
cuRAND Version               : 10010
cuSOLVER Version             : (10, 1, 0)
cuSPARSE Version             : (available)
NVRTC Version                : (10, 1)
Thrust Version               : 100906
CUB Build Version            : 100800
Jitify Build Version         : 60e9e72
cuDNN Build Version          : None
cuDNN Version                : None
NCCL Build Version           : None
NCCL Runtime Version         : None
cuTENSOR Version             : None
cuSPARSELt Build Version     : None
Device 0 Name                : NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080
Device 0 Compute Capability  : 75
Device 0 PCI Bus ID          : 0000:1A:00.0
Device 1 Name                : NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080
Device 1 Compute Capability  : 75
Device 1 PCI Bus ID          : 0000:68:00.0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here are the logs:

```
CUDA_PATH: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1
Wheel shared libraries: C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\cupy\.data\lib
Adding DLL search path: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin
Adding DLL search path: C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\cupy\.data\lib
CuPy wheel package built for CUDA 10.1
CuPy CUDA library directory: C:\Users\Dmitri/.cupy/cuda_lib
Looking for cudnn version 8.0.5 (cudnn64_8.dll)
Rejected candidate (not found): C:\Users\Dmitri/.cupy/cuda_lib\10.1\cudnn\8.0.5\lib\cudnn64_8.dll
Rejected candidate (not found): C:\Users\Dmitri/.cupy/cuda_lib\10.1\cudnn\8.0.5\lib64\cudnn64_8.dll
Rejected candidate (not found): C:\Users\Dmitri/.cupy/cuda_lib\10.1\cudnn\8.0.5\bin\cudnn64_8.dll
File cudnn64_8.dll could not be found
Trying to load cudnn64_8.dll from default search path
Library cudnn could not be preloaded: Could not find module 'cudnn64_8.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
Looking for cudnn version 8.0.5 (cudnn_ops_infer64_8.dll)
Rejected candidate (not found): C:\Users\Dmitri/.cupy/cuda_lib\10.1\cudnn\8.0.5\lib\cudnn_ops_infer64_8.dll
Rejected candidate (not found): C:\Users\Dmitri/.cupy/cuda_lib\10.1\cudnn\8.0.5\lib64\cudnn_ops_infer64_8.dll
Rejected candidate (not found): C:\Users\Dmitri/.cupy/cuda_lib\10.1\cudnn\8.0.5\bin\cudnn_ops_infer64_8.dll
File cudnn_ops_infer64_8.dll could not be found
Trying to load cudnn_ops_infer64_8.dll from default search path
Library cudnn could not be preloaded: Could not find module 'cudnn_ops_infer64_8.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
Looking for cudnn version 8.0.5 (cudnn_ops_train64_8.dll)
Rejected candidate (not found): C:\Users\Dmitri/.cupy/cuda_lib\10.1\cudnn\8.0.5\lib\cudnn_ops_train64_8.dll
Rejected candidate (not found): C:\Users\Dmitri/.cupy/cuda_lib\10.1\cudnn\8.0.5\lib64\cudnn_ops_train64_8.dll
Rejected candidate (not found): C:\Users\Dmitri/.cupy/cuda_lib\10.1\cudnn\8.0.5\bin\cudnn_ops_train64_8.dll
File cudnn_ops_train64_8.dll could not be found
Trying to load cudnn_ops_train64_8.dll from default search path
Library cudnn could not be preloaded: Could not find module 'cudnn_ops_train64_8.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
Looking for cudnn version 8.0.5 (cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll)
Rejected candidate (not found): C:\Users\Dmitri/.cupy/cuda_lib\10.1\cudnn\8.0.5\lib\cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll
Rejected candidate (not found): C:\Users\Dmitri/.cupy/cuda_lib\10.1\cudnn\8.0.5\lib64\cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll
Rejected candidate (not found): C:\Users\Dmitri/.cupy/cuda_lib\10.1\cudnn\8.0.5\bin\cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll
File cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll could not be found
Trying to load cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll from default search path
Library cudnn could not be preloaded: Could not find module 'cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
Looking for cudnn version 8.0.5 (cudnn_cnn_train64_8.dll)
Rejected candidate (not found): C:\Users\Dmitri/.cupy/cuda_lib\10.1\cudnn\8.0.5\lib\cudnn_cnn_train64_8.dll
Rejected candidate (not found): C:\Users\Dmitri/.cupy/cuda_lib\10.1\cudnn\8.0.5\lib64\cudnn_cnn_train64_8.dll
Rejected candidate (not found): C:\Users\Dmitri/.cupy/cuda_lib\10.1\cudnn\8.0.5\bin\cudnn_cnn_train64_8.dll
File cudnn_cnn_train64_8.dll could not be found
Trying to load cudnn_cnn_train64_8.dll from default search path
Library cudnn could not be preloaded: Could not find module 'cudnn_cnn_train64_8.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
Looking for cudnn version 8.0.5 (cudnn_adv_infer64_8.dll)
Rejected candidate (not found): C:\Users\Dmitri/.cupy/cuda_lib\10.1\cudnn\8.0.5\lib\cudnn_adv_infer64_8.dll
Rejected candidate (not found): C:\Users\Dmitri/.cupy/cuda_lib\10.1\cudnn\8.0.5\lib64\cudnn_adv_infer64_8.dll
Rejected candidate (not found): C:\Users\Dmitri/.cupy/cuda_lib\10.1\cudnn\8.0.5\bin\cudnn_adv_infer64_8.dll
File cudnn_adv_infer64_8.dll could not be found
Trying to load cudnn_adv_infer64_8.dll from default search path
Library cudnn could not be preloaded: Could not find module 'cudnn_adv_infer64_8.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
Looking for cudnn version 8.0.5 (cudnn_adv_train64_8.dll)
Rejected candidate (not found): C:\Users\Dmitri/.cupy/cuda_lib\10.1\cudnn\8.0.5\lib\cudnn_adv_train64_8.dll
Rejected candidate (not found): C:\Users\Dmitri/.cupy/cuda_lib\10.1\cudnn\8.0.5\lib64\cudnn_adv_train64_8.dll
Rejected candidate (not found): C:\Users\Dmitri/.cupy/cuda_lib\10.1\cudnn\8.0.5\bin\cudnn_adv_train64_8.dll
File cudnn_adv_train64_8.dll could not be found
Trying to load cudnn_adv_train64_8.dll from default search path
Library cudnn could not be preloaded: Could not find module 'cudnn_adv_train64_8.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
Not preloading nccl
Looking for cutensor version 1.2.2 (cutensor.dll)
Rejected candidate (not found): C:\Users\Dmitri/.cupy/cuda_lib\10.1\cutensor\1.2.2\lib\cutensor.dll
Rejected candidate (not found): C:\Users\Dmitri/.cupy/cuda_lib\10.1\cutensor\1.2.2\lib64\cutensor.dll
Rejected candidate (not found): C:\Users\Dmitri/.cupy/cuda_lib\10.1\cutensor\1.2.2\bin\cutensor.dll
File cutensor.dll could not be found
Trying to load cutensor.dll from default search path
Library cutensor could not be preloaded: Could not find module 'cutensor.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Could you add `cupy.show_config()` output?

Comment: Thanks! Hmm the environment seems fine. Could you also add `print(cupy._environment._get_preload_logs())` output?

Comment: @kmaehashi done!

Comment: The log also seems fine... Please check that `nvrtc64_101.dll` and `nvrtc-builtins64_101.dll` is in `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin` and NOT in any other directory in PATH.

Comment: any luck in this thread?

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall the current version of cupy.

```
pip uninstall cupy
```

Then execute the following line

```
pip install cupy-cuda12x
```

Also make sure you have installed the latest "CUDA Toolkit" and Nvidia "Studio" Driver (not Game Ready Driver). Hopefully this should fix the problem. It worked for me.